# Map EF raw SQL query to specific properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I've got a fairly complex SQL query that instead of converting to LINQ it was recommended to just run it as Raw SQL. Looking at the examples I have to give it an object to make a list from. So I created a class that has a better representation of property names versus what the table column names are. However, I can't seem to use those properties and have to make property names that match the database's column name.

I have a class I called Region that has the following properties

```
public string RegionName { get; set; }
public string DepartingStation{ get; set; }
```

However, the DB column names are

```
REG_NAME
DEP_STATION
```

If I have property names the same as the DB column it returns results. However, I would prefer to us the better represented property names. Is there way I can map the class property names to the specific DB fields?

```
using (ApiDbContext db = new ApiDbContext())
{
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<Region>(sbQuery.ToString()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Almost always the most simple is the more effective. I suggest to ouput column aliases  from raw sql to match class properties names.

Comment: Do you mean I an some how alias the properties in the class?

Comment: In your sql query, instead of output REG_NAME, DEP_STATION, etc you will do REG_NAME as RegionName , DEP_STATION as DepartingStation,....

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to add all over the records into a generic list? Then I could loop through that list and populate different info. Similar to maybe using a DataSet or DataReader that I would then use to populate a class?

Comment: Yes sure, actually your variable results will be a local generic list of Region items,  List<Region>.  You could loop and do what you need to do.

Comment: @E-Bat Your comments should be an answer. It would be a good answer. Please write it, so that it can be useful for othe rpeople

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I suggest to output column alias from raw sql to match class properties names. So if you have:

```
public class Region {
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public string DepartingStation{ get; set; }
}
```

then you write raw sql like this:

```
var subquery = @"
select 
 REG_NAME as RegionName,
 DEP_STATION as DepartingStation
from Table1"
```

With that in place you can safely call:

```
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<Region>(subquery).ToList();
```

where *results* will be a local generic list of Region items, `List<Region>.` You could loop and do what you need to do with it.

Comment: What happens if you don't have access to alter the procedures?  When attempting to map at the model-level I have used System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.Schema [Column("ColumnName")], it still doesn't work.  I can certainly use a  data-specific model that then gets converted into my public model with whatever naming I want, but that seems unnecessary.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: thanks to Oracle's useless naming convetion, this is not an option for me :-(